# Definition of homogeneous Sobolev spaces $\dot W^{-s,q}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

For the homogeneous Sobolev spaces $\dot H^{-s}$, we can define its norm like this: $$\Vert f \Vert_{\dot H^{-s}}=\Vert \Lambda^{-s} f\Vert_{L^2}$$, i.e., we use fractional derivatives to define it. Then can we define $$\Vert f \Vert_{\dot W^{-s,q}}=\Vert \Lambda^{-s} f\Vert_{L^q}$$ for $q \in (1,\infty)$? We can consider the domain as $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Are you working o a domain in the first equation? It is not clear to me, Also, how do you define $\Lambda$ over a domain. I guess you are just taking $\Delta^{-1/2}$ for the standard Laplacian with Neumann boundary conditions.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez The domain is $\mathbb R^2$.